# child component ngOnInit not called when visit child route after first visit

Tags: angular

this is my root route in app module

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'viewParent',
        loadChildren: () => import("./modules/view-parent/view-parent.module").then((m) => m.ViewParentPageModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]



    following is my child route for child module 

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ViewParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "items",
        loadChildren: () => import("src/app/modules/view-parent/view-parent-items/view-parent-items.module").then((m) => m.ViewParentItemsModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],

        }

    ]
  }
];

    this is route for viewParentItemsModule

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ViewParentItemsComponent
  }
];
```

when i am on viewParent route and then navigate to viewparent/items then first time ngOnInit of child component called and then i navigate back to viewParent and then again navigate to viewparent/items then ngOnInit not called

Comment: Since you're not destroying and initializing again the child component, the onInit gets called only when it's initialized. If you want to keep the child component alive and also want to trigger some logic when it's loaded into view again, just move the logic to AfterViewInit - it will get executed each time it loads in DOM again.

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to destroy the child component I guess this the link that may help you

https://medium.com/@rawllopes/destroy-child-components-from-parent-component-in-angular-be3d4ad9cf3b

but if it is not the case, you can add your code in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook.